# printing out floating point value

Tags: printf, x86-64, nasm

Trying to print out floating point number from st0 register.

Currently I have to pass the value through xmm0 register then call c function printf.

is there any way to pass the value from the st0 register straight into printf?

Comment: Related: [How to print a single-precision float with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37082784) you need to print it as a `double` or `long double`, passed in xmm0 or the stack respectively.

Answer (score 2):

the [x86-64 ABI's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) *require* that you use XMM registers to pass around floating point values, so unless you write a custom `printf` that uses your own ABI (calling convention), there is really no way around this.