# How to print a single-precision float with printf

Tags: assembly, printf, x86-64, calling-convention

I'm trying to print a floating point number in x86_64 assembly but it just prints the value as zero.

There's a few questions about this already. One appeared to be resolved by ensuring that [you set the number of vector registers you're using in %al](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20594800/331041). Another showed that [you need to have a stack alignment of 16 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26839444/331041). But, I'm doing both those things and still not getting correct output.

This is my program:

```
# prints a floating point value
.section .rodata
.fmt: .string "num: %f\n"
.num: .float 123.4

.section .text
.global main
.type   main, @function
main:
  subq $8, %rsp     # 16-byte alignment

  # print my number
  movss .num, %xmm0 # load float value
  movq $.fmt, %rdi  # load format string
  movb $1, %al      # use 1 vector register
  call printf

  # exit
  addq $8, %rsp     # undo alignment
  movq $0, %rax     # return 0
  ret
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**[`printf(3)`'s `%f` format specifier wants a `double`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)**.
There is no way to get printf to accept a `float`, only `double` or `long double`.

---

**C's default argument promotions** specify that calls to variadic functions like `foo(char *fmt, ...)` promote `float` to `double`, and perform the usual integer promotions of narrow integer types to `int`, for trailing args that match the `...` part of the prototype.  (The same applies to all args for calling functions with no prototype.)  [N1570 6.5.2.2 Function calls, subsections 6 and 7](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=99).

**Thus C provides no way for a caller to pass a `float` to `printf`**, so it has no conversion for it.  **`%f` means `double`**.  `%lf` also works for `double` [in modern printf implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf), C99/C11 and C++11. You can safely use the same `%lf` format string with a `double` for `printf` and `scanf`.

**Note that `scanf` is different**.  `float *` and `double *` aren't affected by those promotions, so you can actually scan into a `float` with `%f`.

---

## Load with `CVTSS2SD .num(%rip), %xmm0`

If you look at [compiler output](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:%27-xc+--std%3Dgnu99+-O3+++-Wall+-Wextra+-fverbose-asm+-mtune%3Dsandybridge+-mtune%3Dgeneric+-fno-fast-math%27,source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0Afloat+f+%3D+123.4%3B%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++printf(%22%25f%5Cn%22,f+)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3), you'll see gcc do everything you did.  It uses [RIP-relative addressing for static storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967075/why-does-this-movss-instruction-use-rip-relative-addressing) as usual.

GCC also uses `pxor` to zero the register first to break the false dependency on the old value of `%xmm0`.  ([`cvtss2sd`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTSI2SD.html)'s poor design leaves the upper 64 bits of the destination unchanged.)  [GCC errs on the side of caution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60688348/why-does-adding-an-xorps-instruction-make-this-function-using-cvtsi2ss-and-addss), and inserts xor-zeroing instructions to break false dependencies in many cases.

---

**You're probably getting 0 because the upper bits of xmm0 happen to be zero**.  When `printf` looks at the low 64 bits of xmm0 as a [`double` (IEEE binary64 on x86)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), it finds the bit pattern for `123.4f` in the low 32 bits of the mantissa, and the rest zero.  As a 64-bit `double`, this bit-pattern represents a very small (subnormal) number, so it comes out as zero with `%f`.

You can try the equivalent with a `float`, (e.g. on http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), setting some bits in the low half to see what you get.

If you used `%g` (scientific notation) or `%a` (hex representation of the `double` bit-pattern), the non-zero bits would show up.  (Unless maybe if you had Denormals Are Zero mode enabled in the MXCSR, although glibc might use purely integer stuff to pick apart FP bit-patterns when converting to base-10 strings; it's a hard problem.)

Comment: It's amazing to me that despite having written C++ for years and using printf many, many times... I never knew this.

Comment: @cgmb: yeah, it's non-obvious.  I forget, but it might not even be possible to pass a `float` to a var-args function in C.  The promotion rules specify conversion to `double`.  I expect if it were possible, at least GNU C would have a format specifier for it.  (Like `%hf` or something).  For me, I really only clued in to this limitation from looking at asm, since otherwise the compiler always does the conversion for you.  (Also, from actually from wanting to print a `float` with `%a` hex-style formatting)

Comment: (update: it's *not* possible to pass a `float` to the `...` part of a variadic function, or unprototyped function in C.  The default argument promotions always apply.)