# Float vector loading into xmm register

Tags: assembly, nasm, simd

I'm learning about SIMD instructions and trying to apply it to my code. The objective is to use `addps` in a simple example: carry two `float` vectors (with four values) and adds the ith-value of each one storing the answer in the `result` vector. I tried putting each vector in an `xmm` register and I've already tried with `movaps` and `movups` but apparently with no success.

The code is like this:

```
section .data
    a dd 1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4f
    b dd 0.4f, 0.5f, 0.6f, 0.7f
    result dd 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
    format db "Content = {%.1f, %.1f, %.1f, %.1f}", 10, 0
    formatResult db "Result = {%.1f, %.1f, %.1f, %.1f}", 10, 0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    movaps xmm0, [a]
    movaps xmm1, [b]

    addps xmm0, xmm1

    movaps [result], xmm0

    mov rdi, formatResult
    movaps xmm0, [result]
    call printf

    mov eax, 60
    syscall

section .externals
    extern printf
```

I am generating and executing `file` like this:

```
nasm -f elf64 -o file.o file.asm
gcc -nostartfiles -o file file.o -no-pie
./file
```

And the answer obtained is

```
Content = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4}
Content = {0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7}
Result = {172.8, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0}
```

I managed to correctly display the values of vectors `a` and `b` loading value by value with `movlpd` into a different `xmm` register (see below), which is not the purpose since I want them all to be in the same register to be able to use `addps`.

```
movlpd xmm3, [a + 24]
movlpd xmm2, [a + 16]
movlpd xmm1, [a + 8]
movlpd xmm0, [a]
lea rdi, [format]
mov al, 4
call printf ; Shows "Content = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4}"
```

Another point that is intriguing me: when trying to reproduce the problem using the `asm` function directly in C code, the correct result appeared:

```
asm( "movaps %1, %%xmm0\n\t"
      "movaps %2, %%xmm1\n\t"
      "addps %%xmm0, %%xmm1\n\t"
      "movaps %%xmm1, %0\n\t"
          : "=m" (c)
          : "m" (a), "m" (b)
     );
```

Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong and how to fix this problem?

Comment: How is `printf` supposed to know that the four values you want are packed in `xmm0`?

Comment: Each `double` arg to printf goes in a separate XMM register, according to the AMD64 System V calling convention.  You need shuffles and `cvtps2pd`.  (There is no conversion specifier for `float` because C variadic function default argument promotion from float to double makes it impossible to ever pass a `float` to printf from C; `%f` wants a `double`).

Comment: Also, `movlpd` is not the load instruction you're looking for; use `movsd` which zero-extends instead of merging a new low half into an existing register value, requiring the old value as an input to an ALU uop as well as the load.

Comment: Related: [How to print a single-precision float with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37082784) .  Also, you don't need inline asm in C to look at values; use a debugger like GDB to examine registers as you single-step the machine code you made with NASM.  e.g. `p $xmm0.v4_float`